# How can I format in java?

Tags: java, formatting

This is what I currently have so far

```
public String toString() {
    return this.make + " " + this.model + " " + this.year + " $"
            + this.price + " " + this.mpg;
}
```

I need to format it to these specifications

1. Make: left-justified and will be no more than 10 characters long
2. Model: left-justified starting in column 11 and will be no more than 10 characters long
3. Year: left-justified and starting in column 21
4. Price: will be output according to the following money format $99,999.00
5. MPG: will be output according to the following format: 99.0.

Please help, I'm lost.
Thanks

Comment: use String.format() http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

`String.format()` is useful for this. It functions similarly to printf in C if you have used it. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 0):

look here:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/

According to the article, you gotta format like this

```
 return String.format("%s %s %s $%s %s",this.make,this.model,this.year,this.price,this.mpg);
```